# Executing different .cmd Files inside Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, cmd

Im trying to execute a .cmd file inside of my Powershell Script. How can i implement that?

Each Checkbox (if checked) should execute another .cmd file.

Here's the Powershell Code i got so far. (instead of the command i just checked if the chexboxes are even selected):

```
#----------------------------------------------
#Checkbox Events
#----------------------------------------------

$handler_button1_Click= 
{
$listBox1.Items.Clear();    
if ($checkBox1.Checked)    {  $listBox1.Items.Add( "Checkbox 1 is checked"  ) }
if ($checkBox2.Checked)    {  $listBox1.Items.Add( "Checkbox 2 is checked"  ) }
if ($checkBox3.Checked)    {  $listBox1.Items.Add( "Checkbox 3 is checked"  ) }
if ($checkBox4.Checked)    {  $listBox1.Items.Add( "Checkbox 4 is checked"  ) }
if ($checkBox5.Checked)    {  $listBox1.Items.Add( "Checkbox 5 is checked"  ) }
if ($checkBox6.Checked)    {  $listBox1.Items.Add( "Checkbox 6 is checked"  ) }

if ( !$checkBox1.Checked -and !$checkBox2.Checked -and !$checkBox3.Checked -and !$checkBox4.Checked -and !$checkBox5.Checked -and !$checkBox6.Checked) {   $listBox1.Items.Add("No CheckBox selected....")} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it the cmd file:

```
& C:\Path\To\cmd.cmd
```

Since you only fill listBox1 when you have a checked box, you can significantly simplify the last test.

```
if ($listBox1.Items.Count -eq 0) {
    $listBox1.Items.Add("No CheckBox selected....")
}
```